# Content-type for token request in OAuth2

Tags: json, urlencode, oauth-2.0

Getting curious about https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1

Take a look:

> The client constructs the request URI by adding the following
> parameters to the query component of the authorization endpoint URI
> using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" format

...and the server has to respond with "application/json".

The questions are:

1. Why should we use explicitly "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"?
2. Are there any obvious benefits from urlencoded?
3. What stops me from accepting both urlencoded and json here? Seems, that I am not really violating RFC this way.

Comment: I'm curious about why do you say `I am not really violating RFC`? it clearly
said `using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" format`

Comment: @ZoT Surprisingly, while implementing _both_ content types, client still gets correct response using urlencoded request.
So, my "what" is about practical reasons for urlencoded. And I am still "wat" of urlencoded request with json response.

Answer (score 5):

I faced with this question too. I don't know if there are any benefits from urlencoded but big player in this industry auth0.com is using `application/json` content type for both request and response.

[image]

Comment: OAuth0 have updated their doc since, it uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` now. https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#authorization-code-flow43